# Maven embedded deploy not working with org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient version 4.4

Tags: maven, apache-httpclient-4.x, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-embedder

Within my application I have to (mvn) deploy artifacts programmatically. I do this with the help of the maven-embedder artifact and some really simple code:

```
MavenCli client = new MavenCli();
int result = client.doMain(new String[] { "deploy" }, "C:/some/path/to/my/pom", System.out, System.out);
```

To be able to do this, I had to add the following dependencies to my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
  <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
  <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
  <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
  <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Problem is, when I change the version of httpclient to version 4.4 (the most recent one), I get the following error when trying to deploy:

```
4840 [main] WARN Sisu  - Error injecting:   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/TrustStrategy
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)   
    ... 72 more
```

Anybody got an idea, why deploy works fine with version 4.3.x of org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient and fails with version 4.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the version of HttpCore? which HttpClient is based upon, still resolves to 4.3.x. Try explicitly setting it to 4.4

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```